# Deploy WordPress using S3 to be used in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS, I'm running code on its EBS environment. I wanna regularly deploy code to the beanstalk environment to make updates to all our running instances.

But I also have a WordPress blog for our main website separate from the main website code. I have already setup the RDS instance to be used by WordPress. But the thing is every time I deploy code to our main beanstalk environment it overrides the files of WordPress that we have available locally. For example if some author made a new post before i deployed the code, the WordPress files gets overwritten, removing the new post files (images and stuff).

So my question is, how can I detach WordPress from our beanstalk environment? I don't want to create a separate beanstalk environment just for WordPress.

Is there any way I can use S3 buckets to host WordPress files and then make the files somehow available in the beanstalk environment we're running for our main site without creating a new environment? If there's an option then what happens to dynamic files being uploaded by user? Will they be saved in S3 by WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely **separate WordPress from your application**. They are different systems, there's no reason to run them on the same host.

There are some extensions for WordPress that can **publish the WordPress site as static HTML**, which can then be hosted from an Amazon S3 bucket. This makes the site read-only so interactive features won't work (eg search, eCommerce) but it's fine for normal blog pages.

- [WP Static HTML Output](https://wordpress.org/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/)
- [Simply Static](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/simply-static/)
- [WP-Static](https://github.com/chnm/WP-Static)
- [Question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-export-a-WordPress-site-to-a-static-HTML-i-e-how-do-you-remove-all-WordPress-functionality-from-a-WordPress-theme-to-turn-it-into-a-plain-HTML-theme-and-are-there-any-%E2%80%98export-as-HTML%E2%80%99-type-features-available)

If that's not suitable, simply run it on a separate EC2 instance outside of the Beanstalk environment. You might even consider using [Amazon Lightsail](https://amazonlightsail.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to me that your are not using the right configurations that belong to a wordpress + EBS installation.

1. EBS creates a new application version when you deploy.
2. Therefore you are cannot access anything from the previous application version *including uploads folder*
3. Conclusion, you need to detach **dynamic files** from the application level while keeping the database the same.
4. How to? Use either a mounted EFS and/or S3. In combination with the Wordpress [S3 offload plugin](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/)

I am assuming you are using an RDS database that doesn't run on the host instance. If not, that is definitely not recommended. I can highly recommend following the best practices [step-by-step installation including files here.](https://github.com/awslabs/eb-php-wordpress/)